# EE 2.8.1 Search. The action you have requested is invalid

Tags: search, 2.8

I'm trying to get a simple search form to work. But I get an error: The action you have requested is invalid.

I have no idea what I'm missing here.

Stash partial with search form:

```
<section>
            {exp:search:simple_form channel="blog" search_in="everywhere" result_page="blog/search"}
            <h2><label for="search">Search</label></h2>
            <div class="searchField">
                <input type="text" name="keywords" id="search" value="" size="18" maxlength="100">
                <button type="submit">Go!</button>
            </div> <!-- /.searchField -->
            {/exp:search:simple_form}
        </section>
```

Stash viewmodel for search results:

```
{stash:embed:layouts:blog}

{exp:stash:set name="body_class"}blog{/exp:stash:set}

{exp:stash:set_list name="detail_data" parse_tags="yes" parse_depth="2"}

    {exp:search:search_results}

        {stash:entry_id}{entry_id}{/stash:entry_id}
        {stash:title}{title}{/stash:title}
        {stash:excerpt}{excerpt}{/stash:excerpt}
        {stash:author}{author}{/stash:author}
        {stash:post_date}{entry_date format='%M %d, %Y'}{/stash:post_date}

    {/exp:search:search_results}

{/exp:stash:set_list}
```

This makes no difference.
    /*TEMP*/
    $config['secure_forms'] = "n";

I hope someone can help me out! Thanks!

Comment: Do you have other problems with secure forms? For instance, can you submit comments? If you are on a corporate firewall that heavily caches URLs, your request could include an expired CSRF token.

Answer (score 1):

Newer versions of ee have more strict security requirements for post data. Try adding the following to your form:

```
<input type="hidden" name="XID" value="{XID_HASH}" />
```

*(This is an older question but I am adding this as it a common resolution to these sorts of problems.)*

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed the "Search" add-on?

Had the same issue, but the search module wasn't installed.

Comment: Hmmm, no the search module is installed.

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar issue, and it seemed to amount to the `{exp:search:search_results}` tag being inside a Stash tag.

So I flipped it inside out and used `{exp:stash:append}`(or append_list in your case) inside of the search_results tag.

Comment: Hmm, no. That doesn't do it either.

Comment: Ok. One last guess. Do you have your no_result_page="" parameter set to the same template as the result_page="" parameter?

Comment: Hmm, well. no_result_page set to the same gives me a blank page. Set to something else gives met the error again. Strange issue this one.